# Jupyter notebook markdown and fenced code blocks

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, ipython

I'm trying this Markdown text:

````
Hello, this should just be a paragraph, and there should be a test of Markdown fenced code block with backticks below:

```
Hello there
This should be in
a code block
```
````

... in a Jupyter notebook markdown cell:

[image: jupyter notebook markdown cell code]

... and this in fact renders fine:

[image: jupyter notebook markdown cell rendered]

---

Now I want to do the same, but I want to store the source text in a Python string variable, then use `IPython.display.Markdown()` to convert it; so I have this code:

````py
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import Markdown as md, Javascript, HTML

mdstr="""
Hello, this should just be a paragraph, and there should be a test of Markdown fenced code block with backticks:

```
Hello there
This should be in
a code block
```
"""

display(md(mdstr))
````

... however, this renders like so:

[image: jupyter notebook python cell markdown]

... and as visible from the screenshot, there is now a missing vertical space between the opening paragraph, and the code block.

So how do I get *the exact same output* with `IPython.display.Markdown`, as I get from just having Markdown text in a Jupyter notebook markdown cell - with a vertical space between paragraph and code block?

Or - if not possible with `IPython.display.Markdown`, what other options do I have, to define Markdown text in a Python string, and then generate output exactly the same, as what a Jupyter Markdown cell would produce, with the same Markdown input string?

Answer (score 1):

With an empty line as the first line of the code block, the display will look like what is expected.

````
mdstr="""
Hello, this should just be a paragraph, and there should be a test of Markdown fenced code block with backticks:

```

Hello there
This should be in
a code block
```
"""
````